# Find a function with constraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find a function $f(x,y,z)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$1.\ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y},\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ exists at $\ \vec{0}$

$2.\ f\ $ is not continuous at $\ \vec{0}$

$3.\ f(x,y,z)\ $ is $\ C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\vec{0}\}$

I struggled but failed ... Could you please help me?

Comment: Hint: conditions (1) and (3) do not depend on the value of $f$ at $0$

Comment: Yeah, I know that $f(\vec{0})$ can be $0$ without loss of generality.

Comment: I actually mean you can define a function satisfying (1) and (3) (which should be easy), and then change its value at $0$ so that it is not continuous at $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(0,0,0)=0$ and
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{x^6+y^6+z^6}$$
for $(x,y,z)\not=0$. 
Then $f(h,0,0)=f(0,h,0)=f(0,0,h)=0$ for all real $h$. This proves existence of the partial derivatives at $0$. $f$ is not continuous at $0$ because $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(1/n,1/n,1/n)=\frac13$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(1/n,0,0)=0$. Obviously, $f$ is $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's excellent.